# 32feet .NET api refusing to connect "The requested address is not valid in its context"

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet

I've been trying to fix this problem for an hour now and it's been giving me a headache. All I'm trying to do is connect a Bluetooth device to my application using the example [on this page](https://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=General%20Bluetooth%20Data%20Connections&referringTitle=Documentation). When the .Connect function is called, a SocketException occurs saying "The requested address is not valid in its context".

I am positive the address of the device I'm pairing is correct; I even discovered devices and used an address from one of the found devices, yet I still got the same error. I've tried both BluetoothService.SerialPort and the MyConsts class example for the Guid, and both raised the same error.

The code I'm using is here:

```
BluetoothAddress addr = BluetoothAddress.Parse("78A2A0FC0BB1");
Guid serviceClass;
serviceClass = BluetoothService.SerialPort;
// - or - etc
// serviceClass = MyConsts.MyServiceUuid
//
var ep = new BluetoothEndPoint(addr, serviceClass);
var cli = new BluetoothClient();
cli.Connect(ep);
Stream peerStream = cli.GetStream();
```

I'm also using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: You should add the relevant code to the question itself instead of linking to an external webpage.

Comment: @mitterdoo  found the solution? I'm struggling on same thing, please share if...

Answer (score 2):

According the documentation it is not issue with the address itself but with services that are running on the device.

https://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Errors

> No Service with given Service Class Id is running on the remote device

Are you sure that device you are using has SerialPort profile running?

Comment: the link is broken. Can you please explain in detail? What is needed here?